# For $r>s\geq1$, convergence in $s^{\text{th}}$ mean does not imply convergence in $r^{\text{th}}$ mean

Tags: mean, convergence, asymptotics, moments

I need a counterexample for the problem: if $r>s\geq1$, convergence in $s^{\text{th}}$ mean does not imply convergence in $r^{\text{th}}$ mean.

The definition for convergence in mean is as follows:
Let $r\geq1$ be a fixed number. A sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3,...$ converges in the $r^{\text{th}}$ mean to a random variable $X$, if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}E(|X_n−X|^r)=0.$$

Comment: @BruceET I have added the definition now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $P(X_n=n)=1/n^\alpha$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-P(X_n=n)$ with $X=0$.

Then,
$$
E|X_n-X|^s=EX_n^s=n^{s-\alpha}
$$

Comment: Ok so basically, $E|X_n-X|^r=n^{(r-a)}$ and for $r>a$, it doesn't converge to 0. Is that how it works  @Cristoph ?

Comment: Yes, for $r\geq a$ actually, as $n^0=1\neq0$.

Comment: Ok thank you so much